# shortcut key of pathfinder pallette

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, pathfinder

I am a new learner in AI CS6. I can't figure out how to make the pathfinder palette appear in the right side in my window. I read an article that told me how to find it. But after a while, it disappeared again and I forgot which keys I used to find it. Can anyone tell me which keys make it appear again?

Answer (score 2):

From the menu choose `Window > Pathfinder` and **look** at the shortcuts presented to the right. Those are the keys needed to open that panel.

[image]